# int and char to float format specifier

Tags: c

I have the foll line of code.

```
int i =125;
char s[]="hello";
char c='z';
printf("%f",i);
printf("%f",c);
printf("%f",s);
```

output  -936283178250000000000.000000 -936283178250000000000.000000  -936283178250000000000.000000  what does this mean??

Comment: It means you're invoking undefined behaviour by using the wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you are using the incorrect formatting directives. Try this instead:

```
printf("%d", i);
printf("%c", c);
```

alternatively, cast your two values in `i` and `c` to float (but that doesn't make much sense, especially in the case of `c`), better to use the right formatting directives.

When you use the incorrect specifier, the behavior is *undefined*, which is what you are observing.

Comment: if i use printf("%f",s) where s is the base address of string then also the SAME real value is displayed.So is this real value a standard error that shows every time u use wrong format specifier???

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get %f from?  If not mistaken %f is a C++ parameter for floating point numbers.

By you using:

```
int i =125;
char s[]="hello";
char c='z';
printf("%f",i);
printf("%f",c);
printf("%f",s);
```

You are telling the compiler that everything you are printing is a floating point number (a.k.a decimal), when in fact it should be

```
printf("%d",i);
printf("%c",c);
printf("%s",s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrong format specifier in printf will result in undefined behavior. When I say undefined behavior, it can give an output but the output may vary from one C implementation to another. Usually this will result in a warning. GCC compiler will issue a warning for this.